# can not longer log in during registration because of condition

Tags: php, function, conditional-statements

On my application users can upload avatars. They are not obliged to upload an avatar so I used a condition to check if users uploaded an avatar. But when I use this condition during the registration users can no longer log in to the application but I retrieve the data in my database. After the registration he sends me always to index.php

```
if (empty($_FILES['upload']['name'])) {
    $user->PPName = "";
    $user->PPNewName = "";
    $user->Register();
} else {
    $PPNewName = time() . $_FILES['upload']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], "uploads/" . $PPNewName);
    $user->PPName = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['upload']['name']);
    $user->PPNewName = $PPNewName;
    $user->Register();
}
```

function (register and loggin in at the same time)

```
public function Register()
{
    // register, salt gebruiken voor het beveiligen van het wachtwoord.
    $salt = "ab4p73wo5n3ig247xb1w9r";
    $db = new Db();
    // gegevens invoeren in de databank
    $insert = "INSERT INTO tblusers (
                          name,
                          email,
                          password,
                          surname,
                          avatar,
                          status,
                          current_challenge_id,
                          feeling

                      ) VALUES (
                          '" . $db->conn->real_escape_string($this->m_sName) . "',
                          '" . $db->conn->real_escape_string($this->m_sEmail) . "',
                          '". $db->conn->real_escape_string(md5($this->m_sPassword . $salt)) . "',
                           '" . $db->conn->real_escape_string($this->m_sSurname) . "',
                          '" . $db -> conn -> real_escape_string($this -> m_sPPNewName) . "',
                              '" . $db -> conn -> real_escape_string("user") . "',
                               '" . $db -> conn -> real_escape_string("1") . "',
                               '" . $db -> conn -> real_escape_string("goed") . "'

                      )";
    $select = "SELECT * FROM tblusers WHERE email = '" . $db->conn->real_escape_string($this->Email) . "';";
    $result = $db->conn->query($select);
    //echo $result;
    if($result->num_rows == 0)
    {
        $db->conn->query($insert);
        //session_start();
        // Inloggen, name in session meegeven, exception tonen die weergeeft dat je bent geregistreerd
        $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
        $_SESSION["name"] = $this->Name;
        $_SESSION["email"] = $this->Email;
        //throw new Exception("Signed up!");
        header("Location: challenge.php?challenge_id=1" );
    }

    else {
        // Bij eerder gebruikte email
        throw new Exception("I'm sorry, your e-mailadres already exist");
    }

}
```

Comment: "Before this condition registering and loggin in at the same time was no issue" **What changed?**

Comment: I changed my information

Comment: where have you defined $conn ?

Comment: I retrieve all the data in the database and I go the to correct page. But he won't log in with the latest user...

Comment: <?php 
 class Db{
  
  private $m_rHost="localhost";
  private $m_rUser="root";
  private $m_rPass="";
  private $m_rDatabase="stimulus1";
  
  public $conn;
  
  public function __construct(){
   $this->conn=@new mysqli($this->m_rHost,$this->m_rUser,$this->m_rPass,$this->m_rDatabase);
    if($this->conn->connect_errno){
     throw new Exception("My apologies my lord, I seem to have misplaced the database");
     
    }
  
  
  }
  
 }

?>

Comment: `//session_start();` - this is commented out, do you have a started session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dit you start the session in the challenge.php page?

Comment: I did
`session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["email"])) {
 header("Location: index.php");
}`

I changed my question now

Comment: You should also make sure you start the session at the register page. It is commented in your question in your register function
    
    //session_start();
   // Inloggen, name in... etc

Comment: Thanks a lot... Thought it wasn't necessary!